# memory allocation when using CCSprite array in cocos2d-android-1

Tags: android, memory-management

I am using cocos2d-android-1 for my gamedevelopment.
I have some confusion related to memory allocation.
Suppose I need an array of sprites.
I will declare them as

```
CCSprite mySprites = new CCSprite[MAX_SPRITES];
```

and while creating i will create them and add to current layer like:

```
for(int i=0;i<MAX_SPRITES;i++)
{
    mySprites[i] = CCSprite.sprite("image_"+i+".png");
    this.addChild(mySprites[i]);
}
```

Now sprites are added to layer but we need to access them while game flow so we will use mySprites;
So my question is when we do this.removeAllChildren(true); for this layer, will it remove all children and also mySprites sprites?
Or do we need to do something like this

```
for(int i=0;i<MAX_SPRITES;i++)
{
    mySprites[i] = null;
}
```

In my game I think memory is leaking if there is simillar case.

We can also use tags to retrive sprites instead of using

```
CCSprite mySprites = new CCSprite[MAX_SPRITES];.
```

Please can you tell me what is the solution for this?

Thanks.